# Java Spring Boot @Scheduled not working in Docker Container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am developing a Java Spring Boot REST API where I have to run scheduled tasks. When developing locally @Scheduled works as expected, but when I deploy the app with Docker @Scheduled is not working anymore.

This is the Dockerfile for the Spring Boot App:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 as base

COPY api/src /app/src
COPY cert /app/src/main/resources
COPY api/pom.xml /app

RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

# Production Environment
FROM openjdk:17-alpine as prod

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Europe/Vienna
RUN date

COPY --from=base app/target/imst-2-0-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app-service/imst-2-0-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
WORKDIR /app-service

EXPOSE 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","imst-2-0-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And this is the Java class where @Scheduled is used:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@Component
@Lazy(value = false)
@Slf4j
public class StudentHoursSchedule {
    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 * * * MON-FRI", zone = "Europe/Paris")
    public void scheduleSaldoCalc(){
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: A few things I'm seeing here. First move the `@EnableScheduling` to the application startup class. you don't need it here. `@Async` has nothing to do with scheduled tasks, so get rid of it both on the class and the method. also get rid of `@Configuration` there is nothing being configured in this class. You only really need on this class `@Component` and `@Slf4j` (this one assuming you have loggers) and at the method level the `@Scheduled` one. Dont' forget about the first one. Also make sure to add logs to actually double check whether it is working or not AT THE correct time

Comment: Another thing I just noticed: You docker `ENV TZ=Europe/Vienna` your job `Europe/Paris` so maybe it is not working at the time you are expecting due to this mismatch.

Comment: @JorgeCampos thanks, I changed everything you said, it is still not working. I am sure it is not working  at all and not just at the wrong time.

Comment: Ok, so then you need to experiment different things. Comment out your method or create a new one that one have a logger on it with the method name. Set its cron expression to every tree seconds and get rid of the zone: `@Scheduled(cron = "0/3 * * * * ?")` add another method same as this with the zone make it run every 4 seconds "0/4" the idea here is to understand if the problem is with the cron configuration. as you mentioned it is running locally.